# Must hacking protobuf jar?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

1.My `namenode` log always prints error log `java.io.IOException: Requested data length 113675682 is longer than maximum configured RPC length 67108864.  RPC came from 172.16.xxx.xxx`

And `datanode` prints `Unsuccessfully sent block report 0x706cd6d00df0effe,  containing 1 storage report(s), of which we sent 0. The reports had 9016550 total blocks and used 0 RPC(s). This took 1734 msec to generate and 252 msecs for RPC and NN processing. Got back no commands`

2.I set `ipc.maximum.data.length` to 134217728 and solved the problem,But unfortunately,i find after set length,my `hdfs` client often can't to write data,but just take a few minutes every time.Then i find the `namenode` throw a new exception,when client can't write,`DatanodeProtocol.blockReport from 172.16.xxx.xxx:43410 Call#30074227 Retry#0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message was too large.  May be malicious.  Use CodedInputStream.setSizeLimit() to increase the size limit.`

like [Referring HDFS-5153](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-5153),it says **The NameSystem write lock is held during this time**.`

I must hacking protobuf jar and set the limit?

**EDIT:**

I find a [Same question](http://community.cloudera.com/t5/CDH-Manual-Installation/CDH-5-5-0-datanode-failed-to-send-a-large-block-report/m-p/34486),but no solution

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are asking?

Comment: @GhostCat,I edit the content.